# Can't Login With sha1 Hashed password

Tags: php, mysql, sha1

I have used sha1 to hash a password upon registration, here's a snippet of code from that:

```
$password = sha1 ($_POST['password']);

    $query = "INSERT INTO admin (forename,surname,email,securityq, securitya,password) VALUES ('$forename','$surname','$email','$securityq','$securitya','$password')";
```

And here is my code at the login form:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = sha1($_POST['pass']);

$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = '$_POST[email]' AND password = $password  ");
```

This wont allow me to log in still, my 'invalid login credentials' is the only result from trying to log in.

Comment: Assuming you are using PHP5.5.0 or greater you should be using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` If you are using a PHP version less than PHP5.5.0 there is a compatibility pack [available here on GitHub](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: No this is not sorted out yet, I have tried all suggestions and am now using sha1 instead of md5 as reccomended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hash the input password before select

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = md5($_POST['pass']);

$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = '$_POST[email]' AND password = '$password'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just hash the password before you compare it with the password in the database.

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password = md5($_POST['pass']);

$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'");
```

..and don't forget to escape your input!

And instead of md5 you should think about using `password_hash` and `password_verify`, because md5 isn't secure any more.

Comment: I've tried this and still my error message 'invalid credentials' is coming up, cant see why.

Comment: Are you sure, you used the same code as I do? In your query you used `$_POST[...]` and I replaced this with the vars

Comment: Yes I have replaced the POST with the password variable.

Comment: Then their might be another issue - form send with get, fields have different names, wrong data stored in the database, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Juste hash before request.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = md5($_POST['pass']);

$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = '$_POST[email]' AND password = '$_POST[pass]'  ");
```

And an advice : you should add a salt at register like :

```
$password = md5 ($_POST['password'].'mysalt123465');

$query = "INSERT INTO admin (forename,surname,email,securityq, securitya,password) VALUES ('$forename','$surname','$email','$securityq','$securitya','$password')";
```

So its harder to crack the pass with brute force.

And `sha1` is better than `md5` for security.

Comment: Advice should really be to use password_hash()/password_verify() rather than simply salting... but at least you are recommending something better than a straight md5

Comment: I agree with you but i am not sure oggle0901 has time / skills to start using this functions. So i prefered expose a simple but stronger solution.

Comment: [Note about sha1 insecurities](http://thehackernews.com/2015/10/sha-1-collision-attack.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hash your password using ***md5()*** function before comparing.

Replace following line:

```
$password = $_POST['pass'];
```

With:

```
$password = md5($_POST['pass']);
```

This should resolve your issue. Bdw I would like to suggest you to use [phpass](https://github.com/rchouinard/phpass) library.

Answer (score 0):

For password, please use ***`password_hash()` as `md5(), sha1(), sha256()`*** are considered weak salts and are easy to hack